# Http response are not visible outside the IIS server but we can able to see the response headers in the localhost

Tags: http, iis, http-headers, response-headers

In our application we use

- Angular as Frontend
- Laravel as API
- IIS Server for hosting

Here we have included the HTTP headers in the IIS server, Angular, and Laravel.
but we can't able to find the response headers outside the IIS server. The response is visible only inside the IIS server localhost live site.

1. Localhost
   [image: livesite in locahost]
2. Outside the server
   [image: livesite outside the server]

We need to resolve this in order to fix vulnerability issues.
Please give some suggestions to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beginners on CORS should spend some time learning new headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` as they control [how response headers enter browser boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers).

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable send error details to remote request.

[image]

And also allow send error to broswer.

[image]

And your `web.config` should add below tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 03213645-6ED3-8955-218D4B4DFC8D-->
```

---

This function is enabled by IIS server to protect the server. It is not recommend to enable enable this feature. This is an expected behavior, not a issue.